# Filter nested list with sub list of elements

Tags: kotlin

In below code , I am trying to filter masterObject list having sublist values of 2 or 3 or 4 . I am not able to filter the list even with single element. Can you guys help me in pointing out what lamba function needs to be used to get expectedList as output

```
fun main() {

    data class ChildObject(var id: Int, var subList: List<Int>)
    data class MasterObject(var identifier: Int, var listObject: List<ChildObject>)

val initialList = arrayListOf<MasterObject>(
    MasterObject(100, arrayListOf(ChildObject(101, arrayListOf(10, 2, 13)), ChildObject(102, arrayListOf(14, 15, 6)), ChildObject(103, arrayListOf(17, 20, 9)))),
    MasterObject(200, arrayListOf(ChildObject(201, arrayListOf(11, 40, 6)), ChildObject(202, arrayListOf(4, 5, 20)), ChildObject(203, arrayListOf(7, 13, 9)))),
    MasterObject(300, arrayListOf(ChildObject(301, arrayListOf(1, 2, 30)), ChildObject(302, arrayListOf(4, 15, 60)), ChildObject(303, arrayListOf(7, 20, 90)))))

/*actual goal is to print final list of master objects containing any of (2,3,4) elements in listobject. for now I am stuck with filtering single element */
val expectedList = arrayListOf<MasterObject>(
    MasterObject(100, arrayListOf(ChildObject(101, arrayListOf(10, 2, 13)))),
    MasterObject(200, arrayListOf(ChildObject(202, arrayListOf(4, 5, 20)))),
    MasterObject(300, arrayListOf(ChildObject(301, arrayListOf(1, 2, 30)),ChildObject(302, arrayListOf(4, 15, 60)))))


    /*not able apply 2 filters and resulting in error*/
    val finalListWithFilter = initialList.filter { masterObject ->
        masterObject.listObject.filter { childObject -> childObject.subList.contains(2) }
    }

    /* prints entire childObject list for any or doesnt print any list for all*/
    val finalListWithAny = initialList.filter { masterObject ->
        masterObject.listObject.any { childObject ->
            childObject.subList.contains(2)
        }
    }

    /*prints list childObject but I need list of masterObject*/
    val finalListWithMap = initialList.flatMap { masterObject ->
        masterObject.listObject.filter { childObject ->
            childObject.subList.contains(2)
        }
    }

    println(finalListWithAny)
    print(finalListWithMap)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do `list.filter { it.subList.contains(2) }`

Comment: `I tried using nested filter`. Show it

Comment: updated object type and my queries

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption of how the filtering works is wrong in this case. Filtering just helps you to narrow down the list of objects. However the contents (the objects themselves) will always look the same regardless of what you filter. This is also the reason why filtering for child elements with id 2, 3 and 4 will basically result in the input list, because each master object has such an element.

As your data class does not contain mutable lists, I assume that a copy of master objects is ok and therefore the following could be a working solution for you:

```
val childrenMatchingIds = listOf(2, 3, 4) // the child id's you are interested in
val result = initialList.mapNotNull { master -> // [1]
  master.listObject.filter { child -> childrenMatchingIds.any(child.subList::contains) } // [2]
    .takeUnless { it.isEmpty() } // [3]
    ?.let { // [4]
      master.copy(listObject = it) // [5]
    }
}
```

1. [`mapNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-not-null.html) ensures that we skip those master objects later where no children match
2. [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) will return us those children where any child is matching the id (therefore [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) within the filter). Note: this list is detached from the original master object. However its contents are valid references to the same objects of the master object's `listObject`-list.
3. here we ensure that if this list is empty, we will continue with a `null` instead (see [scope functions `takeIf` / `takeUnless`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#takeif-and-takeunless))
4. which we then choose to ignore if it is `null` (see [safe calls `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls))
5. finally we copy (see [Data classes - Copying](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying)) the old infos to a completely new (detached - i.e. not the same anymore, but may contain same references) master object, which contains all the details the old one contained, whose references in the `listObject` are the same as those from the old master object, but is filtered.

Back to point 1 & 4: as we filtered out empty children (therefore getting `null` from the `takeIf`), the `mapNotNull` will filter out those master objects that do not contain our children.

Feel free to ask clarifying questions if anything is still unclear.

And yes: there are probably also a dozen of other variants how you could accomplish this. As long as you require a filtered representation of the master object, you will however always require a new master object for that. If your lists were mutable and you rather wanted to remove elements, the solution would be completely different (with all its pros and cons).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
   
    
    val list = listOf(
        mapOf( "id" to 100, "name" to "xyz", "sublist" to listOf(2, 3, 4 )),
        mapOf( "id" to 101, "name" to "abc", "sublist" to listOf(1, 5, 10 )),
        mapOf( "id" to 102, "name" to "qwerty", "sublist" to listOf(2, 6, 12 ))
       )
    
    val result = list.filter { 
        (it["sublist"] as List<Int>).any { it == 2 }
      
    }
    println(result)

    data class ChildObject(var id: Int, var subList: List<Int>)
data class MasterObject(var identifier: Int, var listObject: List<ChildObject>)
val initialList = arrayListOf<MasterObject>(
    MasterObject(100, arrayListOf(ChildObject(101, arrayListOf(1, 2, 3)), ChildObject(102, arrayListOf(4, 5, 6)), ChildObject(103, arrayListOf(7, 2, 9)))),
    MasterObject(200, arrayListOf(ChildObject(201, arrayListOf(1, 4, 6)), ChildObject(202, arrayListOf(4, 5, 2)), ChildObject(203, arrayListOf(7, 3, 9)))),
    MasterObject(300, arrayListOf(ChildObject(301, arrayListOf(1, 2, 3)), ChildObject(302, arrayListOf(4, 5, 6)), ChildObject(303, arrayListOf(7, 2, 9)))))

/*actual goal is to print final list of master objects containing any of (2,3,4) elements in listobject. for now I am stuck with filtering single element */
val expectedList = arrayListOf<MasterObject>(
    MasterObject(100, arrayListOf(ChildObject(101, arrayListOf(1, 2, 3)), ChildObject(103, arrayListOf(7, 2, 9)))),
    MasterObject(200, arrayListOf(ChildObject(202, arrayListOf(4, 5, 2)))),
    MasterObject(300, arrayListOf(ChildObject(301, arrayListOf(1, 4, 3)))))

var resultList = initialList.filter { master ->
    master.listObject.filter { child ->
        child.subList.any { it == 2 } || child.subList.any { it == 3 } || child.subList.any { it == 4 }
    }.size > 0
}

print(resultList)
}
```

Output:

```
 Hello, world!!!
    [{id=100, name=xyz, sublist=[2, 3, 4]}, {id=102, name=qwerty, sublist=[2, 6, 12]}]
    [MasterObject(identifier=100, listObject=[ChildObject(id=101, subList=[1, 2, 3]), ChildObject(id=102, subList=[4, 5, 6]), ChildObject(id=103, subList=[7, 2, 9])]), MasterObject(identifier=200, listObject=[ChildObject(id=201, subList=[1, 4, 6]), ChildObject(id=202, subList=[4, 5, 2]), ChildObject(id=203, subList=[7, 3, 9])]), MasterObject(identifier=300, listObject=[ChildObject(id=301, subList=[1, 2, 3]), ChildObject(id=302, subList=[4, 5, 6]), ChildObject(id=303, subList=[7, 2, 9])])]
```

Comment: updated my object structure. Could you please update your answer as per my object structure ?

Comment: I did, check it out

Comment: Thanks for your help !!. but your answer is printing the input as output. I have updated my input values to show the difference

Comment: You are asking about filtering or about mapping? Filtering is keeping the objects the same, mapping could change the object. I have done filtering, if  you need mapping please add correct question  because currently is "Filter nested list with mini list of elements without using transformations
"